# Facebook Open Graph Action: the last posted action overwrites the previous

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-stream-story, custom-stories

I'm playing with Facebook Open Graph Stories...
When user makes some action inside my mobile app, my FB app creates an "app-owned object" (because it's public) and then pubblish an action to user's facebook profile..

Now I realized that when the same user makes the same open graph action two times or more, the last action overwrite the previous... Is it possible?

For example:

1) User made click on a button on my mobile app, I create the open graph object (called "OBJECT1") and then pubblish the Open Graph ACTION1 to Facebook (Consider I have one action called "REPORT") tagging FRIEND1

2) The same User made another click on a button, I create a second open graph object (called "OBJECT2") and the pubblish the open graph ACTION1 to facebook (the action is the same of point1) tagging FRIEND2

Now the story of the point 1 will be overwritten by the story of the point2, even if I tagged 2 different people... For overwritten I mean that the story on the FRIEND1 profile will be "deleted" or in any case it's not longer visible

Is it possible?

So, to recap, different OBJECT same ACTION but different user TAGS

Can you help me, please?
P.S.: using facebook tools I can see that the app-owned object are ok

Comment: Is possible that the problem is the app owned object?

Comment: Is possible that facebook tagged story has a sort of timeout? I don't understand why they disappear from friend's timeline after unknown time...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the user-owned object but the result was the same... Now I think I understand why the story disappears: because after X time the post is "old" and it disappears... If you wanna manage this, when you post the action you need to pass "expires_in" or "end time" parameters

Comment: even if I set the end_date in 2 weeks, the post disappears from the timeline before the end_date... in few hours.... how is possible?